# How to animate Apple Mapkit flyover?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I watched a **WWDC session** on Apple `Mapkit`
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/206/
I want to make a **flyover animation** showed at 31:33. Change camera angle from top to bottom and spin. But I wrote some code, it crashes. Please help me and tell me what's wrong with my code, thanks!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class Flyover: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7484405, longitude: -73.9856644)
    let distance : CLLocationDistance = 700
    let pitch : CGFloat = 65
    let heading = 90.0
    var camera: MKMapCamera?




    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.mapType = .SatelliteFlyover
        let camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate,fromDistance: distance,pitch: pitch,heading: heading)
        mapView.camera = camera

        //I want the animation to play automatically as soon as the user is in the view.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
            self.camera!.heading += 180
            self.camera!.pitch = 25
            self.mapView.camera = self.camera!
             })



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea, Nirav? I saw you're a pro apple developer

Comment: I have never try this i will search on it if i find answer i will post answer here.

Comment: Thank you. The WWDC video has source code, but it's for OS X.

Comment: "It crashes" isn't a particularly useful description of the problem. Where does it crash? What does the stack look like? Are there any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there.  Try making a new camera like this.

```
mapView.camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: pinLocation, fromDistance: 2000, pitch: 0, heading: 0)

let pinLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

let rotationCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: pinLocation, fromDistance: 2000, pitch: 75, heading: 180)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.mapView.camera = rotationCamera
        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote because this code works fine.

Comment: I think that downvote was me, but it was definitely accidental, as your answer was very helpful (I certainly would have upvoted). Unfortunately I can not find any way to change my vote, it's locked. I'm very sorry. If you know of some way to change a vote, let me know and I'll change it. The rollover does say something about "this vote is locked unless the answer is edited" so maybe make a minor change to your answer and then maybe I can change the vote.

Comment: No worries. :)  I just thought it was weird because Im still using this code.    Thanks for the up vote ;)